# CSS - Hover and change triangle color

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a dropdown list menu with small triangle pointer, when I hover the first item I want the small triangle also change to black color.

This is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebcho06a/1/), Thanks.

**CSS**

```
.username .messages {
    position:absolute;
    margin:22px 0px 0px -70px;
    width:200px;
    max-height:auto;
    color:black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
.username .messages:before {
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-10px;
    left:50%;
    top:-18px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:10px solid black;
    color:black;
    border-color:transparent transparent #fff;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle it says pure js, but I am pretty sure that is jQuery

Comment: Well that may be, but it doesn´t change his problem, because the css is unaffected by that.

Comment: I am trying to fix your problem in the fiddle with jQuery, thats why I stated this. which jQuery library do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the arrow as the `before` pseudoelement of the first link

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebcho06a/5/

```
.messages a:first-child:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-10px;
    left:50%;
    top:-20px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:10px solid black;
    color:black;
    border-color:transparent transparent #fff;
}

.messages a:first-child:hover:before {
    border-color:transparent transparent #000;
}
```

---

Effect on mouseover

[image]

Comment: My OCD made my eye twitch when I saw the triangle wasn't `#1b1e24` ;), but out of the the 3 ways I can think of doing this, this would be the neatest +1